# Error using vl_nnconv An input is not a numeric array (or GPU support not compiled)

Tags: matconvnet

I'm getting this error although I did not compile Matconvnet with GPU support. 
Does anyone else know this error?
May it be a Matconvnet-version issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the source code I was calling, had an explicit flag to call the GPU, I switched it off, now  it is working...